# Transporting Squid

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if there is a way to take a squid mob from the ocean, and somehow transport it inland to my main base.  I think it would look really awesome if I had a few squid in a tank just outside my house.  Problem is, the house is uphill compared with the ocean, and a good 300 blocks or so away.  Anybody have ideas or techniques to get them uphill?  Thanks

Comment: Pushing it through a canal might work. Even the uphill is no problem if you can get it into a tank which you start to fill with gravel (or something) from the bottom up.

Comment: if you have mods use the portal gun or gravity gun, mystcraft can also shorten the distance

Comment: @ratchetfreak why not just use some creative mode or something, then?

Comment: @ver don't equate mods with creative mode, most mods I'm familiar with actually add more challenge to the game

Comment: @ratchetfreak Exactly my point; I'm not 'equating' them. If you want to play some specific version of MC [i.e. vanilla], except you want to have a squid in a pond on a hill, it's a bit of an overkill to install mods. It might be better to just use what's already there and be done with it.

Comment: @ryan you might want to accept answers from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

Squid spawn in water between level 46 and 62 inclusive.

So you could just build a tank, make it really tall, fill it with water, then unbuild it to the right hight once a squid spawns.

Comment: This would actually work, brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Squids now die in a matter of seconds out of water, so I expect the practical answer is "no" without mods. Also, they despawn regularly, so even if you get them into the tank, they won't be there later.

Comment: Are you sure they despawn? They are passive mobs.

Comment: @ChargingPun Yep. They're the only passive mob that still despawns.